# restart and login to remote windows

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, rubygems

we have a requirement to run automation scripts on multiple machines, these scripts works on windows dialog box and other gui objects

automation scripts are failing when windows logoff and as per security our machines logoff automatically

i tried with vbscript code, but below code just make system not to sleep.
I am more looking for a dynamic solution, a code which can login to machine ?

```
' Scoll Lock key do not have any significant 'function. It could be pressed every 20 seconds 'to stop system from Locking Down
Set obj = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")


For i =0 to 10000000

  obj.SendKeys("{SCROLLLOCK}")
  WScript.Sleep 20000 ' time in milisecond

Next
```

do we have any solution in vb script, power shell, ruby or any other language to login to windows. ?

note : i do have access to all the machines i want to access

Answer (score 0):

You should attempt to utilize [Powershell Scheduled Jobs/Scheduled Tasks](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/12/introduction-to-powershell-scheduled-jobs/). Using a job/task will let you execute your automation scripts on the server without needing anyone to log on to the server (the job itself does need to run under an account that has proper security setup to do whatever it is that your job needs to do.)

Jobs/Tasks are designed well to run with out someone logged on to the system.